# In Haskell, I want to read a file and then write to it. Do I need strictness annotation?

Tags: haskell, file-io, io, lazy-evaluation

Still quite new to Haskell..

I want to read the contents of a file, do something with it possibly involving IO (using putStrLn for now) and then write new contents to the same file.

I came up with:

```
doit :: String -> IO ()
doit file = do
    contents <- withFile tagfile ReadMode $ \h -> hGetContents h
    putStrLn contents
    withFile tagfile WriteMode $ \h -> hPutStrLn h "new content"
```

However this doesn't work due to laziness.  The file contents are not printed.  I found [this post](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2009-January/000725.html) which explains it well.

The solution proposed there is to include `putStrLn` within the `withFile`:

```
doit :: String -> IO ()
doit file = do
    withFile tagfile ReadMode $ \h -> do
        contents <- hGetContents h
        putStrLn contents
    withFile tagfile WriteMode $ \h -> hPutStrLn h "new content"
```

This works, but it's not what I want to do.  The operation in I will eventually replace `putStrLn` might be long, I don't want to keep the file open the whole time.  In general I just want to be able to get the file content out and then close it before working with that content.

The solution I came up with is the following:

```
doit :: String -> IO ()
doit file = do
    c <- newIORef ""
    withFile tagfile ReadMode $ \h -> do
        a <- hGetContents h
        writeIORef c $! a
    d <- readIORef c
    putStrLn d
    withFile tagfile WriteMode $ \h -> hPutStrLn h "Test"
```

However, I find this long and a bit obfuscated.  I don't think I should need an `IORef` just to get a value out, but I needed  "place" to put the file contents.  Also, it still didn't work without the strictness annotation `$!` for `writeIORef`.  I guess `IORef`s are not strict by nature?

Can anyone recommend a better, shorter way to do this while keeping my desired semantics?

Thanks!

Comment: If you post the `import` declarations needed to compile your code, other people might help debug it...

Comment: Premature optimization, evil roots, etc.  Why are you afraid to keep the file descriptor for as long as you need it?

Comment: The IORef is not having the effect you perceive.  A value in an IORef can be just as lazy as one you just return from a block.  Your code is equivalent to the also not-working:

    doit file = do {
        d <- withFile tagfile ReadMode $ \h -> do {
            a <- hGetContents h;
            return $! a
        };
        ...

The IORef is just a meaningless hoop to jump through.

But anyway, the punchline is that regular seq is not enough to force a whole String.  You need a deep seq.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason your first program does not work is that `withFile` closes the file after executing the IO action passed to it.  In your case, the IO action is `hGetContents` which does *not* read the file right away, but only as its contents are demanded.  By the time you try to print the file's contents, `withFile` has already closed the file, so the read fails (silently).

You can fix *this* issue by not reinventing the wheel and simply using `readFile` and `writeFile`:

```
doit file = do
    contents <- readFile file
    putStrLn contents
    writeFile file "new content"
```

But suppose you want the new content to depend on the old content.  Then you cannot, generally, simply do

```
doit file = do
    contents <- readFile file
    writeFile file $ process contents
```

because the `writeFile` may affect what the `readFile` returns (remember, it has not actually read the file yet).  Or, depending on your operating system, you might not be able to open the same file for reading and writing on two separate handles.  The simple but ugly workaround is

```
doit file = do
    contents <- readFile file
    length contents `seq` (writeFile file $ process contents)
```

which will force `readFile` to read the entire file and close it before the `writeFile` action can begin.

Comment: Having read the post you link to, I guess you already know some of this.  But since there is more than one laziness issue here I thought it best to be thorough.

Comment: Rather than using 'length contents `seq` ...'. I think you could use the BangPatterns extension and rewrite the previous line as '!contents <- readFile file'.

Comment: That is equivalent to 'contents `seq` ...', which is not enough: it will only evaluate the top-level constructor of contents (i.e. whether it is empty) which means only the first chunk of the file will be read.

Answer (score 11):

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is useing strict IO:

```
import qualified System.IO.Strict as S
main = do
    file <- S.readFile "filename"
    writeFile "filename" file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the file Handle, do lazy write with original one (to the end of file) and lazy read with another. So no strictness annotation involved in case of appending to file.

```
import System.IO
import GHC.IO.Handle

main :: IO ()
main = do
    h <- openFile "filename" ReadWriteMode
    h2 <- hDuplicate h

    hSeek h2 AbsoluteSeek 0
    originalFileContents <- hGetContents h2
    putStrLn originalFileContents

    hSeek h SeekFromEnd 0
    hPutStrLn h $ concatMap ("{new_contents}" ++) (lines originalFileContents)

    hClose h2
    hClose h
```

The [hDuplicate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-IO-Handle.html#v:hDuplicate) function is provided by GHC.IO.Handle module.

> Returns a duplicate of the original handle, with its own buffer. The two Handles will share a file pointer, however. The original handle's buffer is flushed, including discarding any input data, before the handle is duplicated.

With [hSeek](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSeek) you can set position of the handle before reading or writing.

But I'm not sure how reliable would be using "AbsoluteSeek 0" instead of "SeekFromEnd 0" for writing, i.e. overwriting contents. Generally I would suggest to write to a temporary file first, for example using openTempFile (from System.IO), and then replace original.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but you can force the contents to be read by asking for the `length` of the input and `seq`'ing it with the next statement in your do-block. But really the solution is to use a strict version of `hGetContents`. I'm not sure what it's called.