# Write at the beginning of a file in Haskell

Tags: file, haskell

I am trying to add a number at the beginning of a file but the function "appendFile" add at the end of a file.

I wrote this but it didn't work.

```
myAppendFile file = do x <- readFile file
                   writeFile file "1"
                   appendFile file x
                   return x
```

when I do:

```
*main> myAppendFile "File.txt"
```

the error is

```
the ressource is busy (file is locked)
```

so how can I write something at the beginning of a file?

Comment: Does this help? https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-June/078666.html

Comment: The problem is that `readFile` reads file content on demand, and the underlying file handler is still held at the time you want to execute `writeFile`. The solution is to demand the full file content so that the handler gets closed before doing `writeFile`. IMHO the easier way is to use strict IO, you might find [strict](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict/docs/System-IO-Strict.html) useful in this case (at the cost of holding all file contents as a list of `Char`s in memory).

Comment: @Javran: Could you write that as an answer? It addresses the underlying problem pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527271/in-haskell-i-want-to-read-a-file-and-then-write-to-it-do-i-need-strictness-ann

Comment: @TikhonJelvis just added, hope you like it :)

Comment: @Javran: Yep. You did a good job of explaining what was actually going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Gabriel has pointed out, the problem is that `readFile` reads file content on demand, and it closes the underlying file handle only when the file content is fully consumed.

The solution is to demand the full file content so that the handler gets closed before doing `writeFile`.

Short answer: use [readFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-0.3.2/docs/System-IO-Strict.html#v:readFile) from strict package.

```
import qualified System.IO.Strict as SIO
import Data.Functor

myAppendFile :: FilePath -> IO String
myAppendFile file = do
    x <- SIO.readFile file
    writeFile file "1"
    appendFile file x
    return x

main :: IO ()
main = void $ myAppendFile "data"
```

Another simple "hack" to achieve this is to use `seq`:

```
myAppendFile :: FilePath -> IO String
myAppendFile file = do
    x <- readFile file
    length x `seq` writeFile file "1"
    appendFile file x
    return x
```

`seq a b` is basically just `b` plus that when `b` is demanded, `a`(`length x` in this case) is evaluated to [WHNF](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form) before scrutinizing `b`, This is because `length` requires its argument (`x` in this case) to be traversed until the empty list `[]` can be seen, so the full file content is demanded.

Keep in mind that by using strict IO, your program will hold all file contents (as a list of `Char`s) in memory. For toy programs it is fine,
but if you care about performance, you can take a look at [bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) or [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) depending on whether your program deals with bytes or texts(if you want to deal with unicode text). They are both far more efficient than `String`.

Comment: thank you for your answer , but how can I use the System.IO.Strict ? I need to install something ?

Comment: @Raphael yep, you need to installl [strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict). just type in `cabal install strict` (will be installed somewhere under your home directory, root privilege is not required)

Answer (score 5):

I managed to make it works but I used ByteString which is a strict data type:

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

myAppendFile file = do
    x <- B.readFile file
    B.writeFile file $ B.pack "1"
    B.appendFile file x
    return $ B.unpack x

main = myAppendFile "c:\\test.txt"
```

Your code gave you that error because of Haskell laziness.
When you tried to write something in file, the data was not completely read out in `x` because haskell don't need `x` value until that point of code. That's why Haskell still hangs the file.

One more observation, if you have another lazy read before this function, please replace it also with the strict version because you will run into troubles again.

Comment: Is using `Char8` really appropriate here? I think it will fail with unicode files (`Char8` truncates).

Comment: @bennofs It will not fail because the unicode chars are just 1 or more Char8 glued together.

Comment: Oh you're right. Looking at the code, it actually should work. I was scared by the "All Chars will be truncated to 8 bits." note of that module.

Comment: thank you for your answer . Can you explain me what the signification of the "$ B.pack" please ?

Comment: @Raphael B.pack transform from String to Byte8. $ B.pack "1" is the same as (B.pack "1") . In simple words $ open ( an close it at the end of line

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to do this will work in Haskell too. Create a new temporary file, stream bytes from the old one into the temporary one, and then move the temporary one over the old one. You can/should use `ByteString` or some such for efficiency, but you can do the copying in chunks, rather than needing to read everything into memory and then spit it out again. I think `pipes` and `conduit` both offer interfaces that are supposed to make this more pleasant.