# How to import ‘System.IO.Strict’? (HASKELL)

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I am trying to open a file and move the first line last, like so:

```
-- Moves the first line in a file to the end of the file (first line becomes last line)
flyttLn :: FilePath -> IO ()
flyttLn fn = do
    fh <- openFile fn ReadMode
    content <- hGetContents fh
    --putStrLn content 
    let
        (l1:rest) = lines content
        newContent = unlines (rest++[l1])
    hClose fh
    fh2 <- openFile fn WriteMode
    hPutStr fh2 newContent
    hClose fh2
```

Which gives me an error because of lazy-evaluation. So based of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527271/in-haskell-i-want-to-read-a-file-and-then-write-to-it-do-i-need-strictness-ann/2530948) question, I first tried to print the contents of the file, and then re-write them. Which works, except I don't want to print the whole file in the terminal. So I tried to import `System.IO.Strict` like so

```
import qualified System.IO.Strict as SIO
```

But VS Code gives me an error saying

```
Could not find module ‘System.IO.Strict’
It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.not found
```

I have tried to find similar problems, but I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265550/haskell-could-not-find-module-system) question, and it didn't help me solve my problem here.

How can I properly, open a file and edit its content, without having to print the whole file in the terminal? How do I import System.IO.Strict correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The module `System.IO.Strict` is defined in the [`strict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict) package (I found this [using hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=System.IO.Strict)).

I would recommend making a cabal or stack package yourself and adding `strict` to the dependencies.
For cabal I would recommend [the official getting started guide here](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/getting-started.html#creating-a-new-application). For stack you can check out [the official guide here](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have to import `System.IO.Strict` with this:

```
flyttLn :: FilePath -> IO ()
flyttLn file = 
    do 
        fh <- openFile file ReadMode
        content <- hGetContents fh
        let 
            (l1:rest) = lines content
            newContent = unlines (rest++[l1])
        (fn2, fh2) <- openTempFile "." "temp"
        hPutStr fh2 newContent
        hClose fh
        hClose fh2
        removeFile file
        renameFile fn2 file
```