# Haskell XHTML works with manually typed data, but not with data read from file

Tags: html, apache, haskell, xhtml, cgi

I'm working on a board game where each team must submit an order each turn. To prevent abuse, I'm trying to make a login page, where you can select a team, give the team's password, and continue to the next page.

I'm using Haskell, using the resources provided [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Web/Literature/Practical_web_programming_in_Haskell), specifically the "Getting user input" section.

Relevant documentation: [Network.CGI](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cgi), [Text.XHtml](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xhtml-3000.2.2.1)

Imports, relevant data/types, and page function:

```
import Network.CGI
import Text.XHtml

data Team = Team
      {teamID :: Int,
     teamName :: String} deriving Eq
type Lang = Int
type Teams = [Team]

page :: String -> Html -> Html
page t b = header << thetitle << t +++ body << b
```

I have the following loginPage function:

```
loginPage :: Lang -> Teams -> Html
loginPage lang teams = page (["Lépés Bejelentkezés", "Turn Login"] !! lang) $
  form ! [method "post"] << 
    -- [paragraph << (["Csapat: ", "Team: "] !! lang +++ (select ! [name "teamID"] << teamOpts)), -- Generated version, does not work
    {- -}
    [paragraph << (["Csapat: ", "Team: "] !! lang +++
      (select ! [name "teamID"] <<
        [option ! [value "0"] << "Anglia", option ! [value "1"] << "Franciaország"])), --} -- Manually typed version, works perfectly
     paragraph << (["Jelszó: ", "Password: "] !! lang +++ password "password"),
     submit "" (["Tovább", "Next"] !! lang) ]
  where
    teamOpts = map (\t -> option ! [value . show $ teamID t] << teamName t) $ teams
```

The commented line uses teamOpts to generate a list of options, and put them in a select tag, with name "teamID".
In the currently uncommented lines, I wrote (part of) the list I expect when calling teamOpts.

In ghci, both methods produce the exact same HTML. Yet, when calling this program on my webserver (Apache on Rocky Linux), I get the following outputs:

- Generated:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
><head
  ><title
    >L&#233;p&#233;s Bejelentkez&#233;s</t
```

- Manually written:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
><head
  ><title
    >L&#233;p&#233;s Bejelentkez&#233;s</title
    ></head
  ><body
  ><form method="post"
    ><p
      >Csapat: <select name="teamID"
    ><option value="0"
      >Anglia</option
      ><option value="1"
      >Franciaorsz&#225;g</option
      ></select
    ></p
      ><p
      >Jelsz&#243;: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
     /></p
      ><input type="submit" value="Tov&#225;bb"
       /></form
    ></body
  ></html
>
```

As you can see, the generated version simply terminates before even finishing the title tag.

When running the script on the command line (on the webserver), I get the expected outcome (same as Manually written), with the CGI Header: `Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` .
I've also set it to `Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`, but the same problem persists.

Other things I tried:

- Using (teams `seq` ) before creating the list, and other methods of forcing evaluation (Usually the program terminates after returning `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/`
- Trying to debug using a simpler generator: (Works perfectli in cli, but not when loading it, returning up to </t)

```
showTeams :: Teams -> Html
showTeams teams = page "Teams" $
  paragraph << (concat . map (\t -> teamName t ++ ", ") $ teams)
```

- Trying to use strict versions of IO functions (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527271/in-haskell-i-want-to-read-a-file-and-then-write-to-it-do-i-need-strictness-ann)). Worked in cli, but gave `hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)` errors over the web.
- Making sure everything in the directory is owned by apache:apache

The necessary code (newUnitsPage, cgiMain, and main):

```
newUnitsPage :: Lang -> Teams -> Units -> Maybe String -> Maybe String -> Html
newUnitsPage lang teams units tid passwd = page (["Új egységek", "New units"] !! lang) body
  where
    body = paragraph << "PLACEHOLDER" +++ paragraph << fromJust tid +++ paragraph <<  fromJust passwd

cgiMain = do
  -- General setup
  liftIO $ hSetEncoding stdin utf8 -- This doesn't change anything either
  -- (What I use) {- -
  paths' <- liftIO $ listDirectory "./"
  let mapPaths = sort $ filter (=~ "\\.hmap$") paths'
  hmap <- liftIO $ getNewestMap mapPaths
  let teams = fetchTeams hmap --}
  {- For your convenience:
     Write the following to a file named "test.hmap":
     Team {teamID = 0, teamName = "Anglia"}
     Team {teamID = 1, teamName = "Franciaország"}
  -}
  test <- readFile "test.hmap" -- Pretty sure this is where it all goes wrong, but strict reading (Sysem.IO.Strict) does not fix it
  let teams = map (\line -> read line :: Team) . lines $ test

  -- Defaults to 0 (Hungarian)
  mlang <- getInput "lang"
  let lang = maybe 0 (\l -> if l `elem` ["1", "en"] then 1 else 0) mlang

  -- All Inputs
  -- Authentication
  tid <- getInput "teamID"
  password <- getInput "password"

  newUnitOrders <- getInput "newUnitOrders" -- This is for the next page, not yet implemented, since login doesn't work yet.

  -- Number coding for which form to show - method to show certain form based on what inputs exist
  let code = fromJust $ foldM (\lastCode (mInput, code) -> if isNothing mInput then Just lastCode else Just code)
        0 -- If username / password is not supplied, be on login page
        [(tid,1),(password,1), -- If newUnitOrders are not supplied, be on newUnit page
         (newUnitOrders,2)] -- Etc.

  -- The html output
  let pages =
        [loginPage lang teams,
        -- [showTeams teams,
         newUnitsPage lang teams units tid password]

  setHeader "Content-type" "text/html; charset=UTF-8" -- Optional
  output . renderHtml $ pages !! code

main = runCGI $ handleErrors cgiMain
```

I've checked over and over in the documentation, and I've found no indication of what is going wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to duplicate with your `test.hmap` version.  Check the server error logs, and you should see a note about invalid byte sequences in your hmap files, along the lines of:

> ```
> AH01215: xhtml.cgi: test.hmap: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid
> byte sequence): /usr/lib/cgi-bin/xhtml.cgi
> ```

The problem appears to be that Apache runs CGI scripts with `LANG=C`, and the Haskell script will die at some random point in time when it reads unicode data from one of your hmap files.  Making the evaluation stricter may cause the script to fail earlier, but it isn't going to fix the problem.

The easiest fix is probably to add:

```
liftIO $ setLocaleEncoding utf8   -- from GHC.IO.Encoding
```

to the top of your `cgiMain` function.  (Changing the encoding of `stdin` wasn't necessary in my testing.)

Here's my full version of your script used for testing.  Without the `liftIO $ setLocaleEncoding utf8` line, it truncates output exactly the same way you observed; with that line, it works fine:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
import System.Directory
import System.IO
import Network.CGI
import Text.XHtml
import GHC.IO.Encoding

data Team = Team
      {teamID :: Int,
     teamName :: String} deriving (Read, Eq)
type Lang = Int
type Teams = [Team]

page :: String -> Html -> Html
page t b = header << thetitle << t +++ body << b

loginPage :: Lang -> Teams -> Html
loginPage lang teams = page (["Lépés Bejelentkezés", "Turn Login"] !! lang) $
  form ! [method "post"] <<
    [paragraph << (["Csapat: ", "Team: "] !! lang +++ (select ! [name "teamID"] << teamOpts)), -- Generated version, does not work
     paragraph << (["Jelszó: ", "Password: "] !! lang +++ password "password"),
     submit "" (["Tovább", "Next"] !! lang) ]
  where
    teamOpts = map (\t -> option ! [value . show $ teamID t] << teamName t) $ teams

cgiMain :: CGI CGIResult
cgiMain = do
  liftIO $ setLocaleEncoding utf8

  paths' <- liftIO $ listDirectory "./"
  test <- liftIO $ readFile "test.hmap" -- Pretty sure this is where it all goes wrong, but strict reading (Sysem.IO.Strict) does not fix it
  let teams = map (\line -> read line :: Team) . lines $ test

  -- Defaults to 0 (Hungarian)
  mlang <- getInput "lang"
  let lang = maybe 0 (\l -> if l `elem` ["1", "en"] then 1 else 0) mlang

  -- All Inputs
  -- Authentication
  tid <- getInput "teamID"
  password <- getInput "password"

  newUnitOrders <- getInput "newUnitOrders" -- This is for the next page, not yet implemented, since login doesn't work yet.

  -- Number coding for which form to show - method to show certain form based on what inputs exist
  let code = fromJust $ foldM (\lastCode (mInput, code) -> if isNothing mInput then Just lastCode else Just code)
        0 -- If username / password is not supplied, be on login page
        [(tid,1),(password,1), -- If newUnitOrders are not supplied, be on newUnit page
         (newUnitOrders,2)] -- Etc.

  -- The html output
  let pages =
        [loginPage lang teams]
        -- [showTeams teams,
        -- newUnitsPage lang teams units tid password]

  setHeader "Content-type" "text/html; charset=UTF-8" -- Optional
  output . renderHtml $ pages !! code

main :: IO ()
main = runCGI $ cgiMain
```

Comment: Thank you, my code works now. I did look through the logs after I posted the question, but I had to get on the road before I could update my question.

Comment: (Pressed Enter without shift) 
I looked into the error a bit, but I could not pin down the source, since I thought having Apache's default encoding and the stdin (on second thougt, stdout would have been more appropriate) being set to UTF-8 eliminated encoding being the issue.
Sorry for not including the rest of the imports, I have way more than is probably used in my source file, so I just put the most relevant ones.
Thanks for the fix!